# Graph isomorphism in BPP implies it is also in RP

Tags: complexity-theory, probabilistic-algorithms

$$L=\{\langle G\rangle \#\langle H\rangle : H, G \text{ are directed isomorphic graphs }\}$$
$\langle G\rangle$ is adjacency matrix written row by row.
Show that if $L\in BPP$ then also $L\in RP$.
Can you help me ?
I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important observation here is that $GI$ (the language of isomorphic graphs) is self reducible. This means that you can solve the corresponding search problem (finding an isomorphism) using a solution to the decision problem. You can find such a reduction in these [notes](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/complexity/f05/lecture2.pdf) of Jonathan Katz. Now, suppose $A$ is a polynomial time machine with access to an oracle for $GI$, such that when given two isomorphic graphs, $A$ produces an isomorphism.

To put $GI$ in $\mathsf{RP}$, you need to be able to answer "yes" only when you are certain the graphs are isomorphic. Suppose $M$ is a probabilistic polynomial time machine which agrees with $GI$ with high probability (its existence follows from $GI\in\mathsf{BPP}$, with some success amplification). Given graphs $G,H$ as input, execute $M$. If $M$ outputs "no", answer "no". However, when $M$ answers "yes", execute $A$ (the algorithm for finding an isomorphism), while replacing oracle calls with calls to $M$. If $A$ produces a valid isomorphism from $G$ to $H$, output "isomorphic", otherwise output "non-isomorphic".

If $G,H$ are isomorphic, then conditioning on the event that $M$ outputs the correct answer in all of the oracle calls raised by $A$, $A$ finds an isomorphism and the above procedure outputs the correct answer. Since $A$ runs in polynomial time, if the error probability of $M$ is small enough (I leave the details for you), you can use the union bound to bound the probability of having an error in at least one of the oracle calls. If $G,H$ are non isomorphic, then you always output no, which puts $GI$ in $\mathsf{RP}$.

Comment: Ok, I will read it later and accept (and possibly ask questions in comments in case of problems with understanding). Before that, I would like to think more about this exercise - maybe I defeat it on my own. Could you edit and add hints (something like step by step hidden under spoiler) ? I know that you show solution and it is nice. However, beside solution you can add also hints step by step - it will be educationally valuable.

Comment: It is fairly hard solution. Maybe using the fact that $BPP\subseteq P/Poly$ can help here  to simplify this one ?

Comment: Other than self-reducibility, this only requires familiarization with basic probability, which one should possess before talking about randomized complexity classes. If you find the third paragraph to be the hard part, I suggest working on your probability (which is always useful). The second paragraph is only about playing with the definitions (which again, you must make sure you understand). I don't know how to use $GI\in P/Poly$ for this (which is obviously a weaker statement). If you have more specific issues, I'll be happy to help.

Comment: thanks. I think that it was easy if we know fact about self-reducibility. I show you my estimation (union bound) and you try to check it, please. We $n^2$ times launch $M$ in cited algorithm. And exactly once during first checking if $M$ accepts. We assume that $M$ make an error with probablity $1/4$. Then, we can decrease error exponentially - simply polynomially many times we launch $M$. So, we have $(n^2+1)\cdot\frac{1}{4^n}$. For each reasonable $n$ we have that it is upper bounded by $1/4$ what implies that we prove thesis of exercise.

Comment: Seems ok (need more characters).